# Deployment Issue on Web logic

Tags: java, web-services, deployment, webserver, weblogic

We have a Apache CXF Web service that I am trying to deploy on Web logic server (12.1.3) on a windows machine. When I deploy it using a war, it fails on FileNotFound exception for schema (.xsd file). But if i extract or unzip that war file and deploy the extracted folder it doesn't throw any exception and works fine. Does any body know what could be the reason?

Comment: Are you deploying on a linux machine and having permission issues?

Comment: I am deploying on windows machine and what permissions should i check?

Comment: On Linux it might be a problem with the server not having permissions to put the content of the war into some folder (I'm no Web Logic expert but I assume it handles things similar to JBoss which extracts packagaed wars into a temporary folder). You might have the same problem on windows but it's less probable.